# Adobe Premiere Pro "Sliding The Cut"

Tags: premiere, video-editor, editing, adobe, premiere-pro

I want to know if it's possible to "Slide/Move the Cut" so that both clips get shorter or longer depending on slide direction.

[image: Adobe Premiere Pro Timeline]

Right now I'm trimming one clip and then stretching the next clip towards the left to extend. If there's a better way to do this then it'd save us huge time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is:

[image: icon]

Use the [Rolling Edit tool](https://theknowledgeburrow.com/what-is-the-rolling-edit-tool-in-premiere/) by selecting the transition point between the two clips so it goes red:
[image: grab]

Then press <kbd>N</kbd> to select the Rolling Edit Tool, and drag the transition left or right.

Any linked tracks will move together.  If you want to only move the track you selected, hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key (on a Mac) to only move one track.

This is useful for doing [L-cut edits](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/what-is-an-l-cut-in-film/).